# DNN site is broken, I can't access any admin options

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm working on a DNN 6 installation and for some reason all of my admin (even as a super user) menus/options are no longer accessible.

Every time I try to access a simple menu like Admin > Site Settings I get this error:

```
An error has occurred. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: An error has occurred. ---> DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: An error has occurred. ---> DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: An error has occurred. ---> DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: An error has occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at ArtMenuSkinObject.ArtMenuSO.Page_PreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(String FriendlyMessage, Control ctrl, Exception exc, Boolean DisplayErrorMessage) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions.ProcessPageLoadException(Exception exc, String URL) at DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(String FriendlyMessage, Control ctrl, Exception exc, Boolean DisplayErrorMessage) at ArtMenuSkinObject.ArtMenuSO.Page_PreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions.ProcessPageLoadException(Exception exc, String URL) at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Any hints as to what could be happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you do an update to nuke recently?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this, it looks like you are using a custom Skin Object called "ArtMenuSkinObject" and it is having trouble.

You will want to check with the developer of the skin object.

Comment: Hi Mitchel, thank you for getting back. I'll definitely have a look at the skin for the "ArtMenuSkinObject" object. thank you for reaching out!